# Rails - methods that are working but don't seem to be defined anywhere?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to make some changes to [our conference registration platform](https://github.com/bikebike/BikeBike/).  It calls a couple of methods that don't appear to be defined anywhere.  I'm pretty sure they are the methods I need to edit to make the necessary changes.  What am I missing?  Where should I be looking for them?

In [conferences_controller.rb](https://github.com/bikebike/BikeBike/blob/df5cce9efafaade1a9b384da7e749787cbf8856f/app/controllers/conferences_controller.rb), two methods (that I've noticed so far) are called in spite of not having any apparent definitions.

On lines 82-83:

```
# get the current step
@step = current_registration_step(@this_conference, current_user)
```

On lines 96-97:

```
# set up the next step
result = registration_step(@step, @this_conference, current_user)
```

I can't find method definitions for either of these.  I threw some file writes in for debugging and confirmed that current_registration_step() and registration_step() are returning plausible values.  I just can't figure out where they're getting them.

There's a definition for registration_steps() in [conferences_controller.rb](https://github.com/bikebike/BikeBike/blob/df5cce9efafaade1a9b384da7e749787cbf8856f/app/controllers/conferences_controller.rb).  There are definitions for registration_steps() and current_registration_steps() in [registration_helper.rb](https://github.com/bikebike/BikeBike/blob/df5cce9efafaade1a9b384da7e749787cbf8856f/app/helpers/registration_helper.rb).  I've read about some pluralization stuff in Rails so I put file writes in these and even tried commenting a couple of them out with no effect.  It looks like they aren't being called.

Incidentally, "include RegistrationControllerHelper" appears on line 6 of [conferences_controller.rb](https://github.com/bikebike/BikeBike/blob/df5cce9efafaade1a9b384da7e749787cbf8856f/app/controllers/conferences_controller.rb), but I can't find RegistrationControllerHelper defined anywhere in the project.  This seems like it might be relevant?

So... got any idea where registration_step() and current_registration_step() are defined?

Note: I have no background with Ruby or Rails; the person who developed this platform has very little availability right now.  I'm the only volunteer on hand with much coding experience, and these changes would make for a big improvement when we open registration for the upcoming conference.

Comment: Try `pry` (pry-rails for Rails) - add a breakpoint (`binding.pry`) before the call of the method in question, then in an interactive REPL session do `show-source registration_step` etc - it will show the source code itself and the full path to it...

Comment: Found it: https://github.com/bikebike/bikecollectives_core/blob/308dd1f8a8dae5232a77ba16e7c0725ba41bb874/lib/registration_controller_helper.rb#L20 . How: I looked at the Gemfile saw a dependency for `bikecollectives_core`, went to that github page and searched for `registration_step`. Also not sure why you would post this here, couldn't you have just asked your team?

Comment: Thank you!  (Team = one very busy new parent with a full-time job who wrote this code 10 years ago and has been patching it together when it breaks ever since; one busy person who is a very capable coder but not much more familiar with Ruby, Rails, or this code than I am.  All volunteers.  Getting answers on short notice can be... challenging.)  Thank you so much, and thanks to everyone else for the debugging suggestions; it's great to know about tools like pry for future use!

Answer (score 0):

You can use source_location to find these methods, assuming they have been defined the normal way, directly in some Ruby source file:

```
puts method(:registration_step).source_location
```